# Flip the entries in a list without looping

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

In Python, I have a list of zeros and ones (could be very long), e.g.,

```
L = [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
```

I want to flip every entry in the list without use loop, e.g., make 0 to 1 and make 1 to 0.

My idea is the following: this L can be viewed as a binary representation of a real number. So I wish to make L become `0101101001`, then I think there is some bit operation could directly do the flip job. And eventually, I need to make the flipped term back to list, i.e., `1010010110` to `[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]`

Is there a way to implement this idea in Python (without using `numpy`)? Will this method significantly faster than loop? Will this method be the fastest way to achieve this goal?

It is an interview question. I couldn't answer on site. I am not allow to use library like `numpy`.

Comment: You can hide the looping using a list comprehension, but it's still essentially a loop. Even if you transformed it to an int and perform bitwise not, how would you do the conversions between list and int without incurring any loops?

Comment: if it is list or true and false then you can do like ---import operator >>> mylist = [True , True, False] >>> map(operator.not_, mylist) >>> [False, False, True]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using lambda and map:

```
l = [0, 1, 0, 1]
f = list(map(lambda x: int(not x), l))
print(f) # prints [1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Or `lambda x: 1-x`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a list comprehension, and bitwise XOR operator (^) for flipping each bit:

```
def flip(L):
    return [ x ^ 1 for x in L ]

L = [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
print flip(L)
```